# Почему EditText возвращает пустую строку?

Tags: android, kotlin

Создаю диалоговое окно в адаптере к ресайклервью activity_update_dialog_try с помощью шаблона:

```
  val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.Theme_Dialog)
                    builder.setView(R.layout.activity_update_dialog_try)
                    builder.apply {
                        setPositiveButton("Apply", DialogInterface.OnClickListener{dialog, which ->
                            binding1.editDate.text.toString()
                        })
                    }
                    builder.show()
```

С editDate хочу взять строку и закинуть её в бд, но что бы я не писал -- она выдает мне пустое место. Проверял с помощью Log.d, даже если брать байндинг основной активити, всё равно ничего не получается. Как это работает? Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: У вас, наверное, EditText внутри диалога? Если да, то надо именно из диалога брать EditText. Для этого создайте программно переменную с типом ActivityUpdateDialogTryBinding и её вьюху передавайте диалогу для отображения и из неё берите EditText